# Nodejs requests are hanging

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect a user based on their url path and also if they do not have a particular cookie set.

How do I get nodejs to "do nothing" and continue?  The request just hangs if it's executing the `else` statement.  If I remove the `else` statement the request just hangs as well.

```
  app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    if( !(typeof req.cookies['isLoggedIn'] !== 'undefined' && req.cookies['isLoggedIn'] === true ) && req.url.substring(0, 7)  != '/login/' ) {
      res.send(403, "You are not logged in");
    }else{
      //do nothing
    }
    return;
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `next` callback to indicate your middleware doesn't have anything else to do.

```
  app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    if( !(req.cookies.isLoggedIn !== void 0 && req.cookies.isLoggedIn === true) && req.url.substring(0, 7)  != '/login/' ) {
      res.send(403, "You are not logged in");
    }else{
      next();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an output.

for example

```
  res.send(200, "You arelogged");
```

otherwise, your browser will still be waiting for an output.

what do you mean by "continue?"